# Clever if/else structure

Tags: c++, if-statement

I got three variables and I want to do something, if all of them are below a certain `x`. If they are all above, I want to do something else, also I want to do a third thing, if some of the variables are below and some above.

Now I want to do this the most efficient way. For sure, I could first check if all of them are above, if not, check, if all of them are below ....

But is there any more efficient way, I didn't recognize?

Thank you guys and girls for your input.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I told in my question, what my naive idea is about. That is what I 'tried'. I mean not really tried, because ..FOR SURE this works, but I just wanted to know if I can do this more efficient, like I said in the question. Please read the whole question. Thanks :).

Comment: Show Your code, ma be experimental. I think every working algorith is more optimal than non existing

Comment: What should be the output when some of the variables are equal to `x`?

Comment: What do you want to do if two variables are above "a certain x", and the other is equal?

Comment: The simple and readable way is efficient enough. Don't waste time on magic tricks.

Comment: @ChristianHackl The only goal in my current project is to do it as efficient and fast as possible, so I think it does matter.

Comment: @progNewbie: Wasting time and energy on a "fast" solution without measuring the difference to the "slow" solution is not efficient software engineering. Performance is almost always I/O-dependent. This is where *actual* performance gains lie. Your program wastes time on reading from files, painting pixels to the screen or waiting for servers to respond to network requests, not performing boolean logic in the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make three Boolean variables with results of the checks. Now you can check if all three are true using `&&`, and also that all three are `false` using `||`:

```
bool aAbove = a > aMin;
bool bAbove = b > bMin;
bool cAbove = c > cMin;
if (aAbove && bAbove && cAbove) {
    // All above
} else if (!(aAbove || bAbove || cAbove)) {
    // All below
} else {
    // Mixed case
}
```

This should be fine in terms of efficiency when all values are ready for comparison. If it takes time to obtain the values, you may save yourself a third comparison in 50% of the cases at the expense of making your code much less readable:

```
bool aAbove = computeA() > aMin;
bool bAbove = computeB() > bMin;
if ((aAbove == bAbove) && aAbove == (computeC() > cMin)) {
    if (aAbove) {
        // All above
    } else {
        // All below
    }
} else {
    // Mixed case
}
```

Note that the third computation and comparison is done only when the first two comparisons produce identical results. If their result is mixed, the overall result is going to be mixed as well, so the third comparison is irrelevant.

Comment: I wrote in my question, that this is already my 'naive' approach.

Comment: @progNewbie You should write it in code then. From English description it sounds like `if (a>A && b>B && c>C) ... else if (a<=A && b<=B && c<=C) ...`, with all checks performed twice.

Comment: @progNewbie, this solution does only three comparisons compared to your naive approach.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! Then this was my fault. Good to know :).

Answer (score 4):

> Now I want to do this the most efficient way. For sure, I could first check if all of them are above, if not, check, if all of them are below ....

Write expressive code

> But is there any more efficient way, I didn't recognize?

You don't need to. The optimiser will recognise it for you.

If it sees a re-test of invariants it will seek to re-order the code for you (it will succeed).

Always write expressive code that makes logical sense. I have seen gcc and clang's optimisers turn hundreds of lines of c++ code (expressed intent) into one immediate register load because the compiler realised that there could only be one result.

Here's an example (c++14):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

//
// library boilerplate
//
namespace detail {
  template<class Bool>
  constexpr bool all_of(Bool&& b) {
    return b;
  }

  template<class Bool1, class...Rest>
  constexpr bool all_of(Bool1&& b1, Rest&&... rest) {
    return all_of(std::forward<Bool1>(b1)) and all_of(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
  }

  template<class Bool>
  constexpr bool none_of(Bool&& b) {
    return not b;
  }

  template<class Bool1, class...Rest>
  constexpr bool none_of(Bool1&& b1, Rest&&... rest) {
    return none_of(std::forward<Bool1>(b1)) and none_of(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
  }

}

template<class...Bools>
constexpr bool all_of(Bools&&... bs)
{
  return detail::all_of(std::forward<Bools>(bs)...);
}

template<class...Bools>
constexpr bool none_of(Bools&&... bs)
{
  return detail::none_of(std::forward<Bools>(bs)...);
}

//
// external functions
//

void doX();
void doY();
void doZ();

bool testA();
bool testB();
bool testC();

//
// a test
//    
void test()
{
  const bool a = testA(), b = testB(), c = testC();
  if (all_of(a, b, c)) {
    doX();
  }
  else if (none_of(a, b, c)) {
    doZ();
  }
  else {
    doY();
  }
}
```

GCC resolves this to the following assembly language:

```
test():                               # @test()
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        call    testA()
        mov     ebp, eax
        call    testB()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    testC()
        test    bpl, bpl
        je      .LBB0_3
        and     bl, al
        cmp     bl, 1
        jne     .LBB0_5
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doX()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB0_3:
        or      bl, al
        je      .LBB0_4
.LBB0_5:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doY()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB0_4:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doZ()                 # TAILCALL
```

Notice how the compiler uses the ax, bx and ebp registers to cache the state of the tests. Also note the complete lack of calls to `any_of` and `all_of` anywhere in the assembly output.

We could of course write it this way:

```
void test2()
{
  const bool a = testA(), b = testB(), c = testC();
  if (a and b and c) {
    doX();
  }
  else if (not (a or b or c)) {
    doZ();
  }
  else {
    doY();
  }
}
```

Which turns out to yield identical assembly:

```
test2():                              # @test2()
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        call    testA()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    testB()
        mov     ebp, eax
        call    testC()
        test    bl, bl
        je      .LBB1_3
        test    bpl, bpl
        je      .LBB1_3
        test    al, al
        je      .LBB1_3
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doX()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB1_3:
        or      bl, bpl
        add     rsp, 8
        or      bl, al
        je      .LBB1_6
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doY()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB1_6:
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doZ()                 # TAILCALL
```

we could even write this:

```
void test3()
{
  const bool a = testA(), b = testB(), c = testC();
  if (a) {
    if (b) {
      if (c) {
        doX();
      }
      else {
        doY();
      }
    }
    else {
      doY();
    }
  }
  else {
    if (b) {
      doY();
    }
    else {
      if (c) {
        doY();
      }
      else {
        doZ();
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

To yield almost identical code:

```
test3():                              # @test3()
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        call    testA()
        mov     ebx, eax
        call    testB()
        mov     ebp, eax
        call    testC()
        test    bl, bl
        je      .LBB2_4
        test    bpl, bpl
        je      .LBB2_3
        test    al, al
        je      .LBB2_3
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doX()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB2_4:
        test    bpl, bpl
        jne     .LBB2_3
        test    al, al
        je      .LBB2_6
.LBB2_3:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doY()                 # TAILCALL
.LBB2_6:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        jmp     doZ()                 # TAILCALL
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/g/j4q1ke

The moral of this story is the same as the moral of all c++ stories: "Express yourself correctly, clearly, elegantly and succinctly. Then let the optimiser do its job."

The gcc, msvc, intel and clang optimisers have been worked on by thousands of people who are cleverer than I (and probably you) will ever be. It is improbable that our hand-written "optimised" source code will do a better job. Furthermore, future iterations of these compilers will be even better. So even if you never improve your own code, it will be automatically improved whenever you accept a newer version of the compiler.

So I guess the second moral of the story is (contrary to the beliefs of many software managers...), "upgrade your compiler often."

Final note:

We could even get really advanced and use a tuple to hold the results of the conditions. This then means that the set of conditions we are testing is DRY (which is good!). This too, will produce identical code on gcc:

```
namespace detail {
  template<class Tup, std::size_t...Is>
  bool none_of(Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    bool result = true;
    using unwrap = int[];
    void(unwrap{0,
                (result = result and not std::get<Is>(tup),0)...
               });
    return result;
  }

  template<class Tup, std::size_t...Is>
  bool all_of(Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
  {
    bool result = true;
    using unwrap = int[];
    void(unwrap{0,
                (result = result and std::get<Is>(tup),0)...
               });
    return result;
  }
}

template<class...Bools>
constexpr bool none_of(std::tuple<Bools...> const& tup)
{
  constexpr auto N = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Bools...>>::value;
  return detail::none_of(tup, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

template<class...Bools>
constexpr bool all_of(std::tuple<Bools...> const& tup)
{
  constexpr auto N = std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Bools...>>::value;
  return detail::all_of(tup, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

void test4()
{
  // note, the list of conditions is now expressed only once.
  // suddenly our code is trivial to maintain
  const auto conditions = std::make_tuple(testA(), testB(), testC());

  // all_of has obvious meaning, regardless of how many conditions are in the tuple
  if (all_of(conditions)) {
    doX();
  }
  // ditto for none_of
  else if (none_of(conditions)) {
    doZ();
  }
  else {
    doY();
  }
}
```

Comment: My friends have created a circuit made of several dozens of gates. Only after assembling they realized it's mostly combinational logic, so they applied some simple minimizing methods to it. It turned out it was a NOT gate.

Comment: Nice use of advanced C++, and analysis of the results.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider gcc's optimiser never fails to impress me. Having started coding in assembler many years ago, it took a long time to relive myself of the habit of treating the compiler as a complex macro assembler. Now I treat the editor as a storyboard. If the code does not look like english, it's probably not expressed elegantly enough.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming v1,v2 and v3 are your values:

```
switch((v1 < x) + (v2 < x) + (v3 < x))
{
   case 0: // none is smaller
   break;

   case 3: // all are smaller
   break;

   default: // some, but not all are smaller
   break;
}
```

I'm afraid this code is less clear than an explicit if/else succession, and it may well not be faster, but you asked for it ;-).

Epilogue after comment:

Jumps are always slowing program flow, because CPUs must flush execution pipelines. What's almost guaranteed to be faster, and often a lot, is *to avoid jumps entirely* and do (even costly) computations instead. For a trivial and well-suited example, let's assume you want to assign a value to a variable: like a bonus to a salesperson proportionally to the number of regions where sales exceeded x. The following would certainly be much faster than any `if` or `switch` construct:

```
auto bonus = regionBonus * ((v1 >= x) + (v2 >= x) + (v3 >= x));
```

This would result in a bonus payment for each region which qualifies, and 0 in the extreme case of none qualifying. This code would in my opinion warrant a comment. Applications like that (probably using database values, not more than a few hundred salespeople) are also less likely to be a valuable optimization target. But if you are trying to weed the unimportant ones out of a trillion events in an inner loop at the LHC, you would be delighted at the speed improvement.

Comment: Anyone knows, if this is faster then the other answer?

Comment: "Faster" is highly context dependent. Which compiler are you using, what optimization level, which hardware do you have, etc.

Comment: @progNewbie Simply measure it. Implement both methods, run them a lot of times, and time it. There are some gotchas though, like caching, that can make benchmarking a bit difficult, but there's nothing better than timing it yourself.

Comment: @progNewbie: Code is not fast or slow. Not even programs compiled from code are fast or slow. Instances of programs run at one particular moment in time, given specific user input, on specific hardware and operating systems, sharing the computer's resources with dozens of other processes and interacting with the internet, databases or the filesystem... *those things* are fast or slow.

Comment: @ChristianHackl That is akin to claiming that a particular car is not faster than another car because you have to consider the driver's skill, the road conditions, the tires and the moon phase, which is obviously not a useful statement. Whenever such a claim about cars or programs is made (in fact, whenever almost *any* non-trivial statement is made) it is implicitly meant *ceteris paribus:* The statement assumes that other factors are held constant between comparisons. Most of the times, under the same circumstances, we will have measurable performance differences between programs.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: What I wanted to say is that this tiny piece of code is very likely a completely irrelevant (possibly not even measurable) factor in the *total* speed of the software when it will actually be executed somewhere. The OP does not seem to be aware of that, and thus seems to invest resources in a wasteful manner. There are academic merits to the question, of course; if the OP actually wanted to study how the CPU works or how a compiler assembles instructions, rather than just asking how to be "more efficient", then I'd certainly be more positive about it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I completely agree with that.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I execute this little piece of code like a few millions of times. So I think it IS relevant.

Comment: @progNewbie: Well, measure it! Even a few million times may not be that much on modern computers. Whatever you do, do not **guess** :)

Comment: @progNewbie my experiments with gcc suggest that building a bitmask and switching on it is neither elegant, expressive or efficient. The compiler does a better job with the 3 if() statements.

Comment: @RichardHodges As a nitpick, I'm not building a bitmask (but that probably doesn't affect the general validity of your statement).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is more efficient or faster, but it is conservative on memory space but great caution needs to be taken into consideration with this type of programming because it will depend on the architecture of the machine in the endian of the storage of numbers but you could write a function that does a bit mask or bit field such as this little program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct mask {
    // Each Bit Mask needs two bits to store at least 3 possible answers.
    // { 00 = 0, 01 = <, 10 = >, 11 ignored except in the output }
    unsigned char first  : 2;   // -- -- -- **  These are the bits in the mask
    unsigned char second : 2;   // -- -- ** --              
    unsigned char third  : 2;   // -- ** -- --    
    unsigned char output : 2;   // ** -- -- --
};

int getValComparison( unsigned value, unsigned factor ) {
    if ( value > factor ) {
        return 2;
    } else if ( value < factor ) {
        return 1;
    } else if ( value == factor ) {
        return 0;
    }
}

mask setMask( unsigned value1, unsigned value2, unsigned value3, unsigned factor ) {

    mask a;
    a.first  = getValComparison( value1, factor );
    a.second = getValComparison( value2, factor );
    a.third  = getValComparison( value3, factor );

    // Determine the Output Value.
    if ( (a.first == 2) && (a.second == 2) && (a.third == 2) ) {
        // All are 2 or high
        a.output = 2;
    } else if ( (a.first == 1) && (a.second == 1) && (a.third == 1) ) {
        a.output = 1;
    } else if ( (a.first == 0) && (a.second == 0) && (a.third == 0) ) {
        a.output = 0;
    } else {
        a.output = 3;
    }

    return a;
}


int void main () {

    int x,y,z, factor;
    x = 7;
    y = 7;
    z = 7;
    factor = 7;

    mask m = setMask( x, y, z, factor );

    if ( m.output == 3 ) {
        std::cout << "Mixed Cases: " << std::endl;
    } else if ( m.output == 2 ) {
        std::cout << "All are greater than factor " << std::endl;
    } else if ( m.output == 1 ) {
        std::cout << "All are less than factor " << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "All are equal to factor " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All you have to do is change the values of x,y,z to different combinations to see if they are all greater than, all less than, all equal to or mixed cases.

Now If You don't need to keep track of the comparison decisions in the bitfield you can do it with a smaller mask and change the function slight to this instead:

```
struct mask2 {
    unsigned char first  : 2;
    unsigned char second : 2;
    unsigned char third  : 2;
};

int getValComparison( unsigned value, unsigned factor ) {
    if ( value > factor ) {
        return 2;
    } else if ( value < factor ) {
        return 1;
    } else if ( value == factor ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1; // Some Unknown error here.
}

unsigned setMask2( unsigned value1, unsigned value2, unsigned value3, unsigned factor ) {
    mask a;
    a.first  = getValComparison( value1, factor );
    a.second = getValComparison( value2, factor );
    a.third  = getValComparison( value3, factor );

    // Determine the Output Value.
    if ( (a.first == 2) && (a.second == 2) && (a.third == 2) ) {
        // All are 2 or high
        return 2;
    } else if ( (a.first == 1) && (a.second == 1) && (a.third == 1) ) {
        return 1;
    } else if ( (a.first == 0) && (a.second == 0) && (a.third == 0) ) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}

int main () {
    int x,y,z, factor;
    x = 7;
    y = 7;
    z = 7;
    factor = 7;

    unsigned decision = setMask2( x, y, z, factor );
    if ( decision == 3 ) {
        std::cout << "Mixed Cases: " << std::endl;
    } else if ( decision == 2 ) {
        std::cout << "All are greater than factor " << std::endl;
    } else if ( decision == 1 ) {
        std::cout << "All are less than factor " << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "All are equal to factor " << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when it comes to bitfields and unions you have to be aware of the architecture and how different processors and operating systems store the bits in their data types. Some are Little Endian, some are Big Endian. You also have the complication of how signed integers are stored such as their encoding such as two's compliment and others. But this does work to your effect.